# Bias Google Places results to a specific region

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-places-api, gmsautocomplete

I am using the official [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) to create the Address lookup.

In the Android version I am able to bias the result to my area.

For example typing in "123 Main St" shows the Main st in my town first before showing me other results.

In iOS I can't figure out how to do that. I am using the "Add a Full-Screen Control" with the the `GMSAutocompleteViewController` delegate.

There is a `GMSCoordinateBounds` but the example is for a map. I am not using a map.

I have tinkered around with something like this but can't get it to work. Am I even on the right track?

```
- (void) placeAutocomplete : (NSString*) location : Bounds:(GMSCoordinateBounds *)bounds{                                                           
[_placesClient autocompleteQuery:location
                          bounds:bounds
                          filter:filter
                        callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
                          if (error != nil) {
                            NSLog(@"Autocomplete error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                            return;
                          }

                          for (GMSAutocompletePrediction* result in results) {
                            NSLog(@"Result '%@' with placeID %@", result.attributedFullText.string, result.placeID);
                          }
                        }];
}
```

***Any help?***

Answer (score 2):

You can set a bounds on the `GMSAutocompleteViewController` directly, for example:

```
// Present the Autocomplete view controller when the button is pressed.
@IBAction func autocompleteClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
    autocompleteController.delegate = self

    // Set bounds to inner-west Sydney Australia.
    let neBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.843366,
                                               longitude: 151.134002)
    let swBoundsCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.875725,
                                               longitude: 151.200349)
    let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: neBoundsCorner,
                                     coordinate: swBoundsCorner)

    autocompleteController.bounds = bounds

    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how are you calculating the lat/lon of your bounding box? Are you staring in the center of where you are and expanding out 20 miles?

Comment: I don't know about the code above (copypasta from Google's dev site) but if you want to calculate a 20 mile bounding box around a latlng point, the methods in SphericalUtil will help (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/#spherical)

Answer (score 0):

Create a **bounds** based on **your location** and set it as the bounds of **`GMSAutocompleteViewController`**

```
func presentAddressFinder(){
     let autocompleteController = GMSAutocompleteViewController()
        autocompleteController.delegate = self
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
        autocompleteController.autocompleteBounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(currentLocation)
    present(autocompleteController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

here `currentLocation`  is the current device location in `CLLocationCoordinate2D!`